# MySQL Update with variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
        or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('shuttle_service_system') 
or die(mysql_error());

$ID_No=$_POST['ID_No'];
$CurrentBalance = $_POST['CurrentBalance'];
$AddedAmount = $_POST['AddedAmount'];
$NewBalance = $CurrentBalance + $AddedAmount;

$sql = ("UPDATE balance
        SET Balance= '$NewBalance' 
        WHERE ID_No= '$ID_No' ");
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
        echo"Transaction successful!";
} else {
        echo "&nbsp Error";
}
```

Hi guys I'm trying to update my certain values in my database with the use of variables. It updates when I use brute force and not variables. I know my variables are working because I printed them before queuing the update.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the paranthesis outside this `UPDATE` Statement

```
$sql = ("UPDATE balance
        SET Balance= '$NewBalance' 
        WHERE ID_No= '$ID_No' ");
```

It should be

```
$sql = "UPDATE balance
        SET Balance= '$NewBalance' 
        WHERE ID_No= '$ID_No' ";
```

Also, add this `mysql_error()` to read the exact error when your query fails.

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Did you add the `mysql_error()` to your `$result` variable as shown ?

Comment: Yup "$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());"

Comment: and did you get any error messages ? If not have you enabled [`error_reporting`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1003917) ?

Comment: How should removing the parenthesis make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add (dot) symbol.

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE balance SET Balance='".$NewBalance."' WHERE ID_No='".$ID_No."';");
```

This approach is bad and you might want to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/3440545) to prevent SQL injection.